# Exception with Long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java

I need a method that reads numbers from the file ( 1 2 3 4 5)  and finds its sum, if the sum is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE. it throw an exception.
**Question: how to check Long.MAX_VALUE and which class to use in the method itself?**

The method itself:

```
  public static long findSum (String path) throws FileNotFoundException, AccessDeniedException, BadFormatException, MaxValueException, IOException {
         String result1 = readFirstLine (new File ("C: \\ input.txt"));
         String file1 = result1.replaceAll ("\\ s +", "");
         long x = Long.parseLong (file1);
         long i = 0;
         while (x! = 0) {
             i = i + x% 10;
             x = x / 10;
             if (i> Long.MAX_VALUE)
                 throw new MaxValueException ("The sum exceeds the permissible values of Long.MAX_VALUE");
         }
         return i;
```

Comment: I don't think you will find a `long` greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, which might be the reason for your exception never being thrown. You could use a `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` as intermediate storage and compare it to `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Your if condition won't be satisfied ever. Also, please put some effort into reformatting your question.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Math.addExact​(long x, long y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#addExact(long,long)) *(added in Java 8)*:

> Returns the sum of its arguments, throwing an exception if the result overflows a long.

> Throws `ArithmeticException` if the result overflows a long

```java
i = Math.addExact​(i, x % 10);
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since I believe the intent of that code is to reverse the `long` value, you forgot to multiply `i` by `10`, which means that you also need to use [`multiplyExact​(long x, long y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact(long,long)) , or [`multiplyExact​(long x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact(long,int)) *(added in Java 9)*:

```java
i = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(i, 10), x % 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file contents are "1 2 3 4 5", then `x = 12345`, `i = 15` (1+2+3+4+5).

`x >= i` is always true.

If huge numbers are entered, `Long.parseLong(file1)` will throw `NumberFormatException` first.

So you don't need to check for `i`.  You should worry about `Long.parseLong(file1)`.